# How to convert Linux Python 3.4 code with national characters into executable code in windows

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, cross-platform, python-3.4

My national language is Polish.

I've got program in Python 3.4 which I wrote on linux. This program mostly work on text, Polish text. So of course, variable names don't have any special characters, but sometimes I put into them some strings with Polish characters, user will input from keyboard some strings with Polish characters and My program read from files, where I got strings with Polish characters.

Everything work well on Linux. I didn't think about encoding, it just worked. But now i want to make it work on Windows. Can you help me understand, what I should actually do to make this transform?

Or maybe some workaround - I just need to have Windows executable file. Perfect way for this, would be "Pyinstaller", but it work only for python 2.7, not 3.4. That's why I want to make it working on Windows, and in VirtualBox with py2exe compile into executable form. But maybe somone know way for this in Linux, it without this encoding problems, it would be great.

If not, I back to my question. I tried to convert my python scripts in gedit into ISO or CP1250 or 1252, I wrote in the file headline what coding I'm using, it actually worked a little, now my windows error pint me into my files with text form which I read some data, so I converted them too... But it didn't work.

So I decided, that it's no more time for blind trials, and I need to ask for help, I need to understand what encoding is used on windows, which on linux, what is the best way to convert one into another, and how make program read characters in right way.

The best way would be - I guess - not changing anything in encoding, but just make windows python understand what encoding I'm using. Is that possible?

Complete answer for my question would be great, but anything what will point me in right direction will also help me a lot.

---

OK. I'm not sure, if I understand your answer in comments, but tried sending text for myself via mail, coping it in virtualbox into notepad and save as utf_8. Still get this message:

```
C:\Users\python\Documents>py pytania.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytania.py", line 864, in <module>
    start_probny()
  File "pytania.py", line 850, in start_probny
    utworzenie_danych()
  File "pytania.py", line 740, in utworzenie_danych
    utworzenie_pytania_piwo('a')
  File "pytania.py", line 367, in utworzenie_pytania_piwo
    for line in f:                  # Czytam po jednej linii
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1134: cha
racter maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The default source encoding for Python 3.x [is UTF-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/), regardless of what platform it's running on, so there's no need to convert anything at all. If your code runs differently on Windows and Linux, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Zero Piraeus in a comment: *The default source encoding for Python 3.x is UTF-8, regardless of what platform it's running on...*

If you have problems, that probably because your source code has incorrect encoding. You should stick to UTF-8 only (even though [PEP 0263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) allows changing it).

The error message you provided is clear:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1134
```

Python is currently expecting UTF8 (because "UnicodeDecodeError"!), but it encounters an illegal char (0x9d isn't a valid char is UTF8). To diagnose the problem, use [iconv(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) on a Linux machine, to detect errors buy doing a dummy conversion:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-2 -o /dev/null < test.py
```

You can try to reproduce the problem by creating a very simple python file, typically : `print "test €uro encoding"`

Comment: This answer helped me, but I don't remeber if I can check it as correct answer (sorry, so much time).
Thank you.